# My graphics card gets too hot

Tags: 10.04, ati, graphics, hp, temperature

I have a HP G62 with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 graphics card. Back when I was using Ubuntu 10.04 I tried to install the Catalyst drivers and probably other ones too but could not get them working. I would, in the end, end up with blank screens all the time. So I gave up and did not install any drivers (I am also not the only one with the problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8972359, and I have tried everything in the thread).

When I rung sensors in the console I get

```
sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +68.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)                  

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +84.5°C
```

As you can see the graphics card is getting too hot. What can I do about this?

Everything works fine under windows 7 (64bit). I don't know the temp but I can feel and hear the difference (it is much cooler and the fan does not work that much).

Comment: Is this under graphical load or idle?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by graphical load but this is under normal web browsing and reading pdf documents. So it is this hot all the time.

Comment: What is the temperature under windows for reference? Are we sure this is all that hot?

Comment: I would be also worried about the CPU and motherboard temperatures. I would look in the BIOS settings for any temperature readouts, check the air flow in the machine. I would want to know if vents were blocked by fluff and if all fans were working and if dust was collecting on the fan blades. Regards.

Comment: And you should try the drivers again, the drivers for Radeon cards has gotten a tiny bit better, and they are what regulates the fan speeds on the graphics card.

Comment: You can try 10.10 or 11.04, or install newer kernels to see if the issues are fixed. Stuff can change for the better or worse within months in Linux.

Comment: I have the same issue, I have a ideapad, under win7 64bit the cooling system start really rarely, but under ubuntu(I have tried from 10.04) it's getting hotter

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are still using lucid:

You can now install the 2.6.38 kernel from synaptic manager without needing to add PPAs or needing to download the kernel itself from the mainline kernel repository.

Start Synaptic Manager and search for "2.6.38".  Install the generic linux 2.6.38 image and headers packages.  If necessary, also install the backports wireless package.

Retry installing the recommended catalyst driver from "Additional Hardware Drivers".

Answer (score 3):

If you do not install the appropriate driver you can't blame the system for this behaviour.

install the latest AMD ATI proprietary driver and everything will work ok, refer to this page for info http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page and i reccomend to install this driver by generating the .deb packages.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're wrong when you say:"...install the latest AMD ATI proprietary driver and everything will work ok...". This is not tottaly true. There is a known issue about Radeon HD 4570... Too much hot and sometimes the system breaks down. And we should figure it out if there is some kind of linux support for the specific graphic drivers.

Answer (score 1):

What happened on this issue?

Based on the given link, here's the link for the driver fixed the issue, http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/10-1/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

There's a latest driver for linux, http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx